# Declare array with result of find command

Tags: bash, shell

I would like put the result of command `find *.txt` in array and then iterate over the array like this

```
for file in array
do

done
```

I need to put in array because later I need to access to the array. So the solution

```
for file in `find *.txt`
do

done
```

isn't good for me.

Comment: Why are you using `find`? There's no difference between `find *.txt` and just `*.txt`, unless you have subdirectories with names ending in `.txt`. Did you mean `find . -name '*.txt'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array assignment syntax:

```
array=($(find *.txt))
```

If there can be spaces in the filenames, you should put

```
IFS=$"\n"
```

before the above command. If there can be newlines in the filenames, it gets really complicated and I'm not sure of a good way to handle it.

Then you can iterate over it with:

```
for file in "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: Let's hope there are no spaces in the filenames... hope and pray! you daredevil!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` 4, and as you don't appear to be using any other feature of `find` except its ability to recurse through subdirectories, I suggest using the `globstar` option instead.

```
shopt -s globstar
array=( **/*.txt )
```

This avoids spawning an external process in which to run `find`, as well as avoiding any nasty surprises if any of the matching files have whitespace in their names.

Comment: He's not even recursing through subdirectories.

Comment: Then the even simpler `array=( *.txt )` can be used (which doesn't require `bash` 4). This replacement assumes he means to use `find . -name '*.txt'`.

Comment: +1 for simplicity and for being safe against hostile file names.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that you don't have any newlines in your filenames, `mapfile` is a good choice:

```
mapfile -t array < <(find . -name '*.txt')
```

Now if you want something more bullet proof, you can use:

```
mapfile -t array < <(find . -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "${@:0}"' {} +)
eval array=( ${array[@]} )
```

You should feel really bad when seeing this last line: `eval` and unquoted `${array[@]}`. It works and it's bullet proof since the array `array` has been built using the '%q' modifier of `printf`, so everything is nicely escaped or quoted so as to be used safely here!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers all have virtues.  As a complement to them, here is an approach which (a) is safe on even the most difficult file names, (b) allows the full use of the power of `find`, and (c) avoids `eval`:

```
array=()
while read -r -d $'\0'; do
    array+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find . -name '*.txt' -print0)
```